# How do I display ranges of numbers using BETWEEN, COUNT and ALIAS

Tags: sql

How do I display ranges of numbers using BETWEEN, COUNT and ALIAS for ranges of numbers in the same column .

Say 10-19, 20-29, e.t.c

Comment: Please post the query that you tried with.

Comment: Are you looking for regular, known intervals or is this about finding consecutive sequences.

Comment: The hardcoded way is something like `group by case when x between 10 and 19 then1 when x between 20 and 29 then 2 ... end`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  * 
from table 
where number between 10 and 99
```

PS: here table is table name and number is a column name.

Count: it will display the total number of records in a database.

```
select count(names) from table;
```

ALIAS: Alias is used for renaming a column or table

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY round(grouping-field / 10,0)`. What you are doing is using integer division to create the groups of the grouping field. The use of `BETWEEN` wasn't needed. Nor was `ALIAS`.

I did a quick test on some of my data using SQLite:

```
select round((pPrice-5) / 10,0)*10 as grping_bottom, 
  round((pPrice-5) / 10 +1,0)*10 as grping_top_is_below, 
  count(pPrice), sum(pPrice), min(pPrice), max(pPrice)
  from oprice
  group by round((pPrice-5) / 10,0)
```

I used ten as my group size. Your needs may differ.

BUT, you really want to use `FLOOR()` or `CEILING()` or `INT()`, not `ROUND()`, since the values between 5 and 14 will be rounded into the 10-20 group. Since those functions aren't available in SQLite which I have handy, subtracting 5 from the grouping-field creates the proper offset for a 10's grouping.

Untested - if `FLOOR()` function is available then...

```
select floor(pPrice / 10)*10 as grping_bottom, 
  floor(pPrice / 10 +1)*10 as grping_top_is_below, 
  count(pPrice), sum(pPrice), min(pPrice), max(pPrice)
  from oprice
  group by floor(pPrice / 10)
```

Happy coding!